# Code to modify DOM element using DOM.style property

Tags: javascript, dom

So, I've a code that is below which works just fine:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Javascript Practice </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myDiv">
    </div>
    <script>
      var a = 0;
      var b = 255;
      var c = 0;
      var color2 = 'RGB(' + a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ')';

      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = color2;
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.width = 50;
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.height = 300;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've got a lot of feedback saying that when accessing DOM style property, I need to set value as strings such as setting DOM.style.width not to a number like I've done here but appending `w + "px"`

I'm puzzled because I'm using Brackets as a code editor and deploying this on chrome. My code runs just fine and every time I load the HTML page, it initializes a div of the required dimensions. Everyone tells me it won't work which is what's confusing me.

TIA.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl no better way to demonstrate what results I'm getting. Look at the video that I've made - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_p_-Tn0OlEpC_L_a2ov81VENzsbY_qWn

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the feedback. Have tried to edit the title to reflect what I'm trying to achieve with the code.

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline style lengths require units. In [quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mozilla_quirks_mode_behavior), browsers will assume pixels as the unit, if provided with an integer instead of a length. If you are not sure how the browser will handle the value, specify the units.

> *The CSS parser interprets unitless numbers as px (except for `line-height` and any other properties where they have distinct meaning, and except in shorthands).*

**Bonus:** Here is an extensible version of your script.

```js
const state = {
  color : { r : 0, g : 255, b : 0 },
  dimensions : { width : 50, height : 300 }
}

const applyState = (el, state) => {
  Object.assign(el.style, {
    backgroundColor: `rgb(${state.color.r}, ${state.color.g}, ${state.color.b})`,
    width: `${state.dimensions.width}px`,
    height: `${state.dimensions.height}px`
  })
}

applyState(document.getElementById('my-div'), state)
```

```html
<div id="my-div"></div>
```